# How to retrieve value in html from Angular using JHipster

Tags: java, angular, http, header, jhipster

I have an angular function where I wanna display an error message when there is a duplicate record in my database. I tried to retrieve the message I set from 
my backend server using ResponseHeader as seen below:

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("ErrorMessageKey", "error." + errorKey);
    headers.add("ErrorMessageParam", entityName);
    return headers;
```

I was wondering how to retrieve "ErrorMessageKey" in my Angular so that I can display the error message on my html using JHipster. I tried the method below but it failed. My angular code is as follows:

```
private onSaveError(error) { 
    try {
    error.json(); //why need to convert response to json ?

    } catch (exception) {

        error.message = error.text();
    }
    this.isSaving = false;

    this.onError(error);
}

private onError(error) {

    this.alertService.error(error.message, null, null);
}
```

And my HTML code is as follows:

```
   <small class="form-text text-danger"
   [hidden]="!editForm.controls.Name?.errors?.message" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.message"> 
</small>
```

I am pretty sure JhiTranslate portion is wrong but I have no idea what went wrong because there are no error messages being displayed and I cant debug it.
Your help is much required thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is already error handling in EntityResource @PostMapping method:

```
if (entity.getId() != null) {
    throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new cashup cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
}
```

so you can use it.